# How to show all parent and child values in one select dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-7

Hi guys i have topic table where i am storing all topics along with sub topics..and subtopic id i am storing in parent_id column.

Here is my db structure:
[image]

i am getting all topics in dropdown like this.
But i would like to show my subtopics list like this

```
fractions 
fractions>introductions to fractions
fractions>Fractions as division
```

So far i have create childTopics functions in my model:

```
public function childTopics()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Topic::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

And i used in my create function in controller like this:

```
 $topics = Topic::with('childTopics')->parent()->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Here is my ajax call where i am showing all my topics in one place.

```
function getSubjectsTopics(subject_id)
{
    if(subject_id) {
        loading_show();
    axios.get("/master/topic/get-topic-by-subject-id/" + subject_id)
        .then(function(response) {
            var optionHtml = '<option value="0">Parent</option>';
            if(response.data.status) {
                $.each(response.data.subject_topics, function(i,v) {
                    optionHtml += `<option value="${v.id}">${v.name}</option>`;
                 });
            }

            $("#ddl_topic_type").html(optionHtml).attr('disabled', false).select2();
            loading_hide();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            loading_hide();
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!'
            })
        })
    } else {
        $("#ddl_topic_type").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

In this ajax call itself i would like to show my  subtopics with parent topic name itself.

Can anyone help me how can i show it.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here is my response output
[image]

Here is functions to get topics based on subject:

```
public function getTopicsBySubjectID($subject_id)
{
    $topics = Topic::where("subject_id", $subject_id)->get(['id', 'name']);

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'subject_topics' => $topics], 200);
}
```

Comment: Hi, you mean `optgroup` where we  group sub options based on some parent option ?  If yes show your `response` output .

Comment: yes my  output is showing liek this in dropdown  fractions  introductions of fraction fractions as division one by one it is showing like this in my select option

Comment: Add `response` output i.e : do `console.log(response)`  copy that output  and add in your question .

Comment: edited my question can u please check once

Answer (score 1):

You can use `optGroup` to group your sub option in a group where `optGroup` will have the name of the `subject name` .Your current `ajax response` show all `subject_topics` together so if the first value `fractions` is subject name you can put condition inside `each` loop to check if `i`(position) is `0` then append `optgroup`.

***Demo code*** :

```js
var response = {
  'data': {
    'status': 'success',
    'subject_topics': [{
      'id': 0,
      'name': 'fractions'
    }, {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'fractions of booksss of subject'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'fractions of sub'
    }]

  }
};
var optionHtml = '<option>Select....</option>';
if (response.data.status) {
  $.each(response.data.subject_topics, function(i, v) {
    if (i == 0) {
      optionHtml += `<optGroup label="${v.name}">` //considering 1st id is subject name
    } else {
      optionHtml += `<option value="${v.id}">${v.name}</option>`;
    }
  });
  optionHtml += `<optGroup>` //close optgroup
}

$("#ddl_topic_type").html(optionHtml).attr('disabled', false).select2();

//or
var response = {
  'data': {
    'status': 'success',
    'subject': 'somesubjectname', //return subject name as well
    'subject_topics': [{
      'id': 0,
      'name': 'fractions'
    }, {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'fractions of booksss of subject'
    }, {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'fractions of sub'
    }]

  }
};
var optionHtml1 = '<option>Select....</option>';

if (response.data.status) {
  //append subject name
  optionHtml1 += `<optGroup label="${response.data.subject}">`
  $.each(response.data.subject_topics, function(i, v) {
    optionHtml1 += `<option value="${v.id}">${v.name}</option>`;
  });
  //subject name ..
  optionHtml1 += `<optGroup>`
}

$("#ddl_topic_type1").html(optionHtml1).attr('disabled', false).select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
<select id="ddl_topic_type"></select>
<select id="ddl_topic_type1"></select>
```

Comment: cant we  make the structure the way i showed in my questions..because i can have n number of subchilds under one child..so by that time this optgroup structure wont work rite?

Comment: for example under introduction if i have one more child and under that if i have another one? by that this optgroup wont work rite?

Comment: I need to see then your json proper structure . Above answer is according to your provided console result .

Comment: can we make a group so i can show it there..i have done same thing in my laravel..so i can show it..

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply this comments will automatically will have chat option

Comment: Sorry i can't you can show required json format here only use pastebin or jsfiddle .

Comment: can u please make this chat move to group..i couldtn able to make it up

Comment: hi swati..i have posted another question with proper json..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65352399/how-to-make-tree-structure-heirarachy-for-select-dropdown-in-laravel-ajax?noredirect=1#comment115537596_65352399

Comment: can you please check it out and help me on that