# How to make tree structure heirarachy for select dropdown in laravel ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

Hi guys i have topics table where i have all my topics along with his sub topics.i got all my topics along with sub topics in json format..now i am trying to show it in my select dropdown in ajax call..but there i can able to see only the parent topic only.
I couldnt able to see my child topics.

Here is my ajax call:

```
function getSubjectsTopics(subject_id)
{
    if(subject_id) {
        loading_show();
    axios.get("/master/topic/get-topic-by-subject-id/" + subject_id)
        .then(function(response) {
            var optionHtml = '<option value="0">Parent</option>';
            if(response.data.status) {
                $.each(response.data.subject_topics, function(i,v) {
                    optionHtml += `<option value="${v.id}">${v.name}</option>`;

                 });
            }
            $("#ddl_topic_type").html(optionHtml).attr('disabled', false).select2();
            loading_hide();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            loading_hide();
            console.log(error);
            Swal.fire({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Something went wrong!'
            })
        })
    } else {
        $("#ddl_topic_type").attr('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

here is my fucntions where i am getting my json data:

```
public function getTopicsBySubjectID($subject_id)
{
    $topics = Topic::where("subject_id", $subject_id)->parent()->get(['id', 'name'])->each(function ($item) {
        $item->child_topics = $item->getTopicRecursive()->toArray();
        return $item;
    });

    return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'subject_topics' => $topics], 200);
}
```

model function:

```
public function getTopicRecursive($main = false)
{
    $main = $main ?: $this;
    $children = $main->childTopics()->get(['id', 'name']);

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $child->setRelation('childTopics', $this->getTopicRecursive($child));
    }

    return $children;
}
```

Now i am trying to show my list like this

```
- fractions
- fractions > introduction to fractions
- fractions > introduction to fractions > What are fractions and its purpose 
- fractions > Fractions as division
```

Here is my json:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
```

(
[items:protected] => Array
(
[0] => App\Models\Topic Object
(
[casts:protected] => Array
(
[grades] => object
)

```
                [connection:protected] => mysql
                [table:protected] => topics
                [primaryKey:protected] => id
                [keyType:protected] => int
                [incrementing] => 1
                [with:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [withCount:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [perPage:protected] => 15
                [exists] => 1
                [wasRecentlyCreated] => 
                [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => fractions
                        [child_topics] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 2
                                        [name] => introduction to fractions
                                        [child_topics] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 4
                                                        [name] => What are fractions and its purpose?
                                                        [child_topics] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [1] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 5
                                                        [name] => int 123
                                                        [child_topics] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => Array
                                                                    (
                                                                        [id] => 6
                                                                        [name] => int 123 subtopic
                                                                        [child_topics] => Array
                                                                            (
                                                                            )

                                                                    )

                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 3
                                        [name] => Fractions as division
                                        [child_topics] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => fractions
                    )

                [changes:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [classCastCache:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dates:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dateFormat:protected] => 
                [appends:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [dispatchesEvents:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [observables:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [relations:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [touches:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [timestamps] => 1
                [hidden:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [visible:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [fillable:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [guarded:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => *
                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Can anyone help me how can i make that structure in my ajax call.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:console.log(response)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335424/how-to-show-all-parent-and-child-values-in-one-select-dropdown-in-javascript

Comment: No it doesn't thats why i have added my question with new code

Comment: could you help me how can i do that

Comment: your question i m not able to understand

Comment: i have that json structure format i want to make that format in my select dropdown.

Comment: post that json data

Comment: i have posted in my question can u please check once

Comment: hi, do `console.log(response)` inside success function of ajax and show that output .

Comment: okay give me 2 mins i will update in my question

Comment: edited my question can u pls check once

Comment: i think you need to create dynamic select if data have child

Comment: dynamic select in the sense? those are all values from my db only..just need to show it in my select dropdown in proper structure..how i show in my question

Comment: hi swati are you there?